# Extend a vector field of normal vectors beyond the surface

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, parametric, curvature

I am not terribly well-versed in differential geometry, so please keep that in mind when answering the question.

We are given a surface in ${R}^3$ defined parametrically by $\vec{r}(u,v)$ where $0\leq u,v\leq1$.  We can find the normal vector at any point $(u_0,v_0)$ by
$$
\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial u}\times \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial v}
$$
The question is how we can extend this into a vector field all throughout $R^3$ rather than just on the surface.

The reason why is because we want to calculate the mean curvature of the surface, which is given by 
$$
-\frac{1}{2}\nabla \cdot \vec{n}
$$
where $\vec{n}$ is a normal vector and I'm not sure how to do this when our surface is given para-metrically by $\vec{r}(u,v)$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to calculate the mean curvature of a surface $M$ at a point $p$, you need to extend the normal vector field to an open neighborhood of $p$ in $R^3$. This can be done by using the implicit function theorem to represent $M$ as the *level surface* of a suitable function $f(x,y,z)$ with nonzero gradient at $p$. Once you have $f$ in a neighborhood of $p$, just take the gradient of $f$ in a possibly smaller neighborhood, normalize it to unit length, and you got your extension.

Comment: Ok I see.  So as an example, if $M$ is the surface given by $\vec{r}(u,v)=\langle u\text{ cos}(v), u\text{ sin}(v), u\rangle$, how could we represent $M$ as a *level surface* of such a function?  In this case, of course, we could also represent $M$ as $z^2=x^2+y^2$ and it is easy, but what if we can't switch back into Cartesian co-ordinates?

Comment: Say I'm not given my surface $M$, but rather, that's what I'm looking for.  I'm looking for $M$ and to know it, I need to know its mean curvature, which comes from the divergence
$$
H=\nabla\cdot\vec{n}
$$
Here, $H$ is given para-metrically by $\vec{r}(u,v)$ where $0\leq u,v\leq 1$ and $||\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial v}||=1$.

See, we're not given explicitly what $\vec{r}(u,v)$ is, but need to know the divergence of it to determine it (through variational methods).

Comment: I thought your original question was to know how the field along the parametrisation can be extended to a field in an open neighborhood. To calculate the mean curvature you need the Weingarten map.  The latter is determined by the first and second fundamental form. The second fundamental form is (up to sign) the matrix of the second derivatives of $r(u,v)$. More details can be found in my class notes [here](http://u.math.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/egreglong.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to extend the unit normal vector field beyond a surface so that the extended field is gradient field, is to assume it constant along the transversal direction to the surface.
But for your problem-to calculate the mean curvature it is sufficient to take Guenter's tangential derivatives $\mathcal{D}_j:=\partial_j-\nu_j\partial_{\nu_j}$ from the normal vector $\nu=(nu_1,\nu_2,\nu_3)$ because $\mathcal{D}_j\nu_k:=\partial_j\nu_k$ but the advantage is that for the derivative $\mathcal{D}_j\nu_k$ you does not need to leave a surface.

References:

1. R. Duduchava, D.Mitrea, M.Mitrea, Differential operators and
   boundary value problems on surfaces. {Mathematische Nach-ric-hten} {9-10}, 2006, 996-1023.
2. R. Duduchava, Partial differential equations on hypersurfaces,
   {Memoirs on Differential Equations and Mathematical Physics} {48}, 2009, 19-74.
3. R. Duduchava, D Kapanadze, Extended normal vector fields and
   Weingarten map on hypersurfaces, {Georgian Mathematical Journal}, {15}, No. 3 (2010), 485--501.

   I can sent you a new paper concerning this problem:
   R. Duduchava, G. Tephnadze, EXTENSION OF THE UNIT NORMAL VECTOR FIELD TO A HYPERSURFACE.